# How to use CKEditor by class in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, class, ckeditor

Is it possible to enable ckeditor by class type?
For example, I tried the following code but getting error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var txtArea= $(".ckeditor");   
    CKEDITOR.replace(txtArea,{ }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`CKEDITOR.replace`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) accepts ids and native element instances. But you're trying to pass jQuery object to it - it cannot work.

You should try this way:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '.ckeditor' ).each( function() {
        CKEDITOR.replace( this );
    } );
} );
```

Or, if you know that there's just one `textarea` to be replaced:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( $( '.ckeditor' )[ 0 ] );
} );
```

See this example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yy6sX/).